# Screen capture / record iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, video, screen-capture, quicktime

**Short Question :**

Is there a mobile app or some desktop software I  can use while my iPhone / iPad is connected to my Macbook Pro that will allow me to record a video of the screen ?

**Long Question :**

I dont quite a lot of mobile site development and testing. When presenting bugs etc to my team I  like to show them a video of what is happening.

For desktop issues I  just open the browser and the use screen capture in Quicktime. Where ever possible I  do the same for iOS issues using the mobile emulator in Chrome, but because its only an emulator it isnt 100% accurate so not all issues show up.

Some issues I  have to use the real device. At the moment I  capture video for this by using one iphone to film on and another to show the issue, but this is not particularly slick.  (I know I  can run a desktop iphone / ipad emulator through Xcode, but this only has Safari on there, not Google Chrome as some issues are browser specific)

Is there a mobile app or some desktop software I  can use while my iPhone / iPad is connected to my Macbook Pro that will allow me to record a video of the screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading **reflector**, it will mirror your screen, allowing you to use a screen recorder on your Mac to record it.

Comment: Apple Mirroring and AirPlay API has been changed, so you won't be able to use Reflector with iOS 9 anymore